# Why is AppBarLayout's elevation changing when a preference is selected?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-preferences, android-appbarlayout

I only added a `PreferenceScreen` to Android Studio's Basic Views Activity template, and I don't know why the `AppBarLayout` flashes when a preference is clicked

[image]

This is not the behavior of any other clickable element with the `AppBarLayout`. Upon inspection of snapshots, it seems this is because there is an elevation change when the preference is clicked. While scrolled down, the elevation goes to 0.0 when a preference is clicked, and then rapidly changes when selected again.

`activity_main.xml` with the app bar and includes `content_main.xml`:

```
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

        <com.google.android.material.appbar.MaterialToolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize" />

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_main" />

    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email"
        android:contentDescription="@string/fab_description" />

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

content_main.xml:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment_content_main"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/nav_graph" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

SettingsFragment class:

```
class SettingsFragment : PreferenceFragmentCompat() {
    override fun onCreatePreferences(savedInstanceState: Bundle?, rootKey: String?) {
        setPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences, rootKey)
    }
}
```

preferences.xml:

```
<PreferenceScreen
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <SwitchPreferenceCompat
        android:key="switch_preference_1"
        android:title="Switch Preference"
        android:summary="An example that uses a switch" />

    <SwitchPreferenceCompat
        android:key="switch_preference_2"
        android:title="Switch Preference"
        android:summary="An example that uses a switch" />

    <SwitchPreferenceCompat
        android:key="switch_preference_3"
        android:title="Switch Preference"
        android:summary="An example that uses a switch" />

    <SwitchPreferenceCompat
        android:key="switch_preference_4"
        android:title="Switch Preference"
        android:summary="An example that uses a switch" />

    <SwitchPreferenceCompat
        android:key="switch_preference_5"
        android:title="Switch Preference"
        android:summary="An example that uses a switch" />

    <SwitchPreferenceCompat
        android:key="switch_preference_6"
        android:title="Switch Preference"
        android:summary="An example that uses a switch" />

    <SwitchPreferenceCompat
        android:key="switch_preference_7"
        android:title="Switch Preference"
        android:summary="An example that uses a switch" />

    <SwitchPreferenceCompat
        android:key="switch_preference_8"
        android:title="Switch Preference"
        android:summary="An example that uses a switch" />

    <SwitchPreferenceCompat
        android:key="switch_preference_9"
        android:title="Switch Preference"
        android:summary="An example that uses a switch" />

    <SwitchPreferenceCompat
        android:key="switch_preference_10"
        android:title="Switch Preference"
        android:summary="An example that uses a switch" />

    <SwitchPreferenceCompat
        android:key="switch_preference_11"
        android:title="Switch Preference"
        android:summary="An example that uses a switch" />

    <SwitchPreferenceCompat
        android:key="switch_preference_12"
        android:title="Switch Preference"
        android:summary="An example that uses a switch" />

    <SwitchPreferenceCompat
        android:key="switch_preference_13"
        android:title="Switch Preference"
        android:summary="An example that uses a switch" />

    <SwitchPreferenceCompat
        android:key="switch_preference_14"
        android:title="Switch Preference"
        android:summary="An example that uses a switch" />

    <SwitchPreferenceCompat
        android:key="switch_preference_15"
        android:title="Switch Preference"
        android:summary="An example that uses a switch" />
</PreferenceScreen>
```

And finally, my MainActivity class:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var appBarConfiguration: AppBarConfiguration
    private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding
    private var isMenuVisible = true // Default value true to show the menu initially

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)

        setSupportActionBar(binding.toolbar)

        val navController = findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment_content_main)
        appBarConfiguration = AppBarConfiguration(navController.graph)
        setupActionBarWithNavController(navController, appBarConfiguration)

        navController.addOnDestinationChangedListener { _, destination, _ ->
            // Determine if the menu should be visible based on the current destination
            val shouldMenuBeVisible = destination.id != R.id.SettingsFragment
            if (shouldMenuBeVisible != isMenuVisible) {
                // Only update the menu if the visibility has changed
                isMenuVisible = shouldMenuBeVisible
                invalidateOptionsMenu() // Trigger a call to onPrepareOptionsMenu
            }
        }

        binding.fab.setOnClickListener { view ->
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                .setAction("Action", null).show()
        }
    }

    override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu): Boolean {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        if (isMenuVisible) {
            menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu)
        }
        return true
    }

    // For dynamically adjusting the contents of the options menu based on the current state or
    // configuration of the application (whether the current version of the application is taking
    // advantage of this function or not).
    override fun onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu: Menu): Boolean {
        super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu)
        // Clear the existing menu to ensure it reflects the current state
        menu.clear()
        // Conditionally inflate the menu based on the current state
        if (isMenuVisible) {
            menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu)
        }
        return true
    }

    override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
        return when (item.itemId) {
            R.id.action_settings -> {
                findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment_content_main)
                    .navigate(R.id.action_global_settingsFragment)
                true
            }
            else -> super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
        }
    }

    override fun onSupportNavigateUp(): Boolean {
        val navController = findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment_content_main)
        return navController.navigateUp(appBarConfiguration)
                || super.onSupportNavigateUp()
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks like `liftOnScroll` being briefly activated. Have you tried disabling it?

Comment: Does the attached image show the problem?